# ModuleNotFoundError even though the Module is present

Tags: python, django, module, sys, modulenotfounderror

I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError for a module that exists. I have a `__init__.py` and imported `sys` but I am still getting a  ModuleNotFoundError error on my django error.

My file structure:

```
|-my_app
   |-folder1
     |-__init__.py
     |-calc.py
   |-folder2
     |-__init__.py
     |-test.py
```

I want to import a function from `test.py` in `calc.py`. This is my code:

```
import sys
from folder2.test import func1, func2

#my code
```

When I run this, I am getting this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2.test'`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `test` is in folder1, so `folder2.test` will look for `folder1\folder2\test.py`, which is why the error comes up.  Try changing the import to `..folder2.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is in folder1, so `folder2.test` will look for `folder1\folder2\test.py`, which is why the error comes up.  Try changing the import to `..folder2.test`.